# Как в PostgreSQL сделать псевдоним столбца из двух или более слов через пробел?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я думала, что в SQL это делается при помощи заключения псевдонима в квадратные скобки, но почему-то при выполнении следующего запроса возникает ошибка:

```
select facid, sum(slots) as [Total Slots]
from cd.bookings
where starttime between '2012-09-01 00:00:00' and '2012-09-30 23:59:59'
group by facid
order by [Total Slots]
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
  Position: 29
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно создать такой псевдоним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заключите alias в двойные кавычки.

Из [документации](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/alias.php):

- *If the alias_name contains spaces, you must enclose the alias_name in quotes.*
- It is acceptable to use spaces when you are aliasing a column name. However, it is not generally good practice to use spaces when you are aliasing a table name.
- The alias_name is only valid within the scope of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
select facid, sum(slots) as "Total Slots"
```